# Зачем так перекрутили вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Речь об [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538033/upload-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0).

Изначально вопрос был "Где написано, что upload файл живет во времеменной папке до окончания работы скрипта?", а не "upload файл живет во времеменной папке до окончания работы скрипта?" - это два совершенно разных вопроса(!)

Comment: И в чем принципиальная разница? Хотите, обратно переведем, в итоге ответом будет - **в доках**, а вам влепят еще десяток минусов и закроют вопрос как не по теме

Comment: я уже где-то писал что для меня тутошный (и вообще любой) рейтинг - ништо. С моей стороні нужно было уточнить, чтобы и ссылку указали и абзац. Ну не заметил я того абзаца о времени жизни upload-файла, решил спросить.

Comment: Вы не учитываете один нюанс: на одном вашем вопросе будет висеть пачка минусов, на другом, на третьем, на четвертом. В итоге пользователи (особенно основные помогающие) увидят это и подумают, что вы задаете низкосортные, ненужные, не стоящие внимания вопросы, запомнят вас и в итоге больше в ваши последующие вопросы вообще не будут заходить. В результате вы в будущем, как минимум, будете ждать долго ответа, а как максимум вообще не дождетесь оного.

Comment: "В итоге пользователи (особенно основные помогающие) увидят это и подумают, ...  не стоящие внимания вопросы..." - ну если пользователи смотрят ТОЛЬКО на рейтиг, и  не читают вопросы, то наверное они в реальной жизни всех людей "встречают по одежке". я вас понял.

Comment: Ваш рейтинг всем абсолютно без разницы. Смотрят не на ваш рейтинг и не на вас, а на оценку вопроса. И если там пачка минусов - значит не спроста, а значит оно того не стоит. И раз вы задаете все время такие низкосортные вопросы, значит и следующие можно пропускать. Но в этом будете виноваты только вы сами.

Answer (score 6):

Тут как ни поверни, ответ получается кратким.

> Где написано, что upload файл живет во времеменной папке до окончания работы скрипта?

**В документации по PHP.**

> upload файл живет во времеменной папке до окончания работы скрипта?

**Да.**

В данном случае вообще не стоило задавать новый вопрос, достаточно было попросить автора ответа добавить ссылку на документацию. Либо вы могли сами её почитать. Буквально на абзац выше того куска кода, который вы опубликовали в первом вопросе:

> По умолчанию принятые файлы сохраняются на сервере в стандартной временной папке до тех пор, пока не будет задана другая директория при помощи директивы upload_tmp_dir конфигурационного файла php.ini.

Comment: а, это... разве это два одинаковых ответа? О том где он "живет" я знал, когда задавал вопрос. та ладно. все хорошо. некогда мне писать ни о чем. лучше код буду писать.